# Prevent default only on some levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a menu that has submenu. When I click on a menu item I am using prevent default because it is a tags, but on the submenu level I don't want to prevent default. I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work so it doesn't affect the top level.

```
<div id="block-menu-block-2">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">6</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">6.1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$('#block-menu-block-2 ul li').on("click", function() {
if ($(this).children().is('ul')) {
    if ($(this).find('ul').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).find('ul').hide("blind");
        $(this).removeClass('menuItemSelected');
        $(this).find('ul').removeClass('menuItemSelected');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('li ul').hide("blind");
        $(this).parent().find('.menuItemSelected').removeClass('menuItemSelected');
        $(this).find('ul').show("blind");
        $(this).addClass('menuItemSelected');
        $(this).find('ul').addClass('menuItemSelected');
    };
    event.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

Here is a codepen for reference: http://codepen.io/mathiasha/pen/bVpMyo

Comment: use `$('#block-menu-block-2 > ul > li > a')` instead of `$('#block-menu-block-2 ul li')`

Comment: doesn't make sense to prevent default on an `<li>`, there is no default. Event should be on the `<a>`

Comment: @Pot-Nut not necessarily, events bubble up not down. If `<a>` isn't block and filling whole `<li>` quite easy to click `<li>` and not `<a>`

Comment: @charlietfl My bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added some stuff. Changed some stuff. Couldn't paste into codepen from my phone so this might not work. Code first, then word wall.

```
$('#block-menu-block-2 ul li').each (function () { 
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find ('ul:first').length > 0) {
        $this.click (function () {
            if ($this.find ('ul:visible').length > 0) {
                $this.removeClass ('menuItemSelected').find ('ul').removeClass('menuItemSelected').hide ('blind');
            } else {
                $this.parent ().find ('ul li').hide ('blind');
                $this.parent ().find('.menuItemSelected').removeClass  ('menuItemSelected');
                $this.addClass ('menuItemSelected').find ('ul').show ('blind').addClass ('menuItemSelected');
            }
        }); 
    }
});
 $('#block-menu-block-2 > ul > li > a').click (function (e) {
    if ($(this).find ('ul:first').length > 0)
        e.preventDefault ();
});
```

The real answer lies in only putting the preventDefault only on the a tag and only when it is the immediate child of a li tag tjat is the immediate  child of a ul tag that is the immediate child of the block-menu. See the last 3 lines.

The rest of the code below should only add the click listener to li tags with ul tags inside. Tried to use chaining to limit the number of jQuery objects created. Might have messed up what it was doing. You only really need to remove preventDefault from where it is and than use the last 3 lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still not quite what I need. The problem is that not all of the menu items has submenu item, so I need a check before preventing default.

Comment: @Hansted i've added the check

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add a class to your submenu triggers, e.g. `.submenu-trigger`, and then use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('submenu-trigger')) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That would add a handler to every item, rather than using event delegation.

Comment: Above is not a delegated event though.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the other menu manipulation and putting the event on `<a>` tags you can simply check if the `<a>` has a sibling `<ul>` and if it does prevent default

```
$('#block-menu-block-2 a').click(function(e){
    if( $(this).siblings('ul').length ){
         e.preventDefault();
    }
    // menu manipulation code

});
```